# Vb.net not loading access database into datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I can't understand why my Access database won't load into a DataGridView for me. I have no errors within my code so I'm unsure as to what is going on. The only error I'm getting is the configuration element is not declared.

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim objConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Students.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    dataGridShow()

End Sub

Private Sub dataGridShow()
    Dim objDS As New DataSet
    Dim objDT As New DataTable
    objDS.Tables.Add(objDT)

    Dim objDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    objDA = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", conn)
    objDA.Fill(objDT)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = objDT.DefaultView

    conn.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```

My app config looks like this. My database is located in bin/Debug

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Don't use the load event.  Put that code in the constructor.  Don't leave your connections open like that.  Put disposable objects in a using-endusing block.  Your database connection has no path, so it can only assume the same path as the executable.

Comment: "I have no errors within my code so im so unsure as to what is going on." - Just because it compiles doe not mean that there are no errors.  You define `objConn`, but never use it.

Comment: @TnTinMn ok.. so how would i solve this problem?

Comment: I noticed as I was editing your question that your app.config is missing a closing bracket at the end of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?`. Is that accurate or just a typo?

Comment: See [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4933958/719186)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open and close your connection. The DataAdapter does that for you. Your connection will never work without a valid connection string so I moved your connection string to the dataGridShow procedure and set the ConnectionString property of your conn object.

```
Private conn As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dataGridShow()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dataGridShow()
        Dim objDS As New DataSet
        Dim objDT As New DataTable
        objDS.Tables.Add(objDT)
        Dim objConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Students.accdb"
        conn.ConnectionString = objConn
        Dim objDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", conn)
        objDA.Fill(objDT)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = objDT.DefaultView
    End Sub
```